# DDD Alternative that also Draws Pretty Pictures of Data Structures

Tags: c, linux, gdb, debugging, ddd-debugger

Is there anything other than DDD that will draw diagrams of my data structures like DDD does that runs on Linux?

ddd is okay and runs, just kind of has an old klunky feeling to it, just wanted to explore alternatives if there are any.

The top part with the grid of this image is what I am talking about:
[image]

Comment: I haven't found anything anywhere that even remotely compares to graphing and debugging capabilities of DDD.  It's a really powerful debugger, and would be hard to replicate.  I do agree that the Motif interface is clunky, which is unfortunate.

Comment: @supercheetah : if you look at Amigable Clark Kant's comment, the developers agree as well :-) Maybe I can find a init file that makes it look a little bit better.  It is powerful as you say though, and I of course appreciate the work of all the developers.

Answer (score 2):

Don't you mind to look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger_front-end) (list of GDB front-ends)?
I suggest this list should be useful.

Comment: Also the plugin for Geany; http://plugins.geany.org/geanygdb/ 
DDD gtk seems dead though; http://www.mail-archive.com/gtkmm-list@gnome.org/msg06825.html

Comment: Well a handy list, but doesn't say if any of them have the particular feature I mentioned unless I am missing it...

Answer (score 1):

I've used zero bugs a few times.  It can do custom visualization.  I don't know if allows the users to effect the gui elements or just how it displays in the text listings.  Check it out, [www.zero-bugs.com](http://www.zero-bugs.com/2.0/advanced.html#visualization).

Answer (score 1):

For those that wanted an answer; you are looking for KDBG.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ZeroBugs data visualizations can be customized via Python scripts. The debugger is now available as open source (and free as in free beer, it can be used for commercial purposes). Check it out at http://zerobugs.codeplex.com/